# Bot Framework Direct Line Only Works in Debugger

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a BOT that uses QnA Maker and LUIS to answer FAQ and requests and I am trying to implement a Direct Line to another BOT. Basically whenever my BOT does not know the answer it sends the user message to the other BOT to check if it knows the answer and outputs the result. The Direct Line works fine when I step through the code with Debugger (the GET request responds with the message I sent and the reply from the BOT). However, when I just run the code normally the response only contains the message I sent and not the reply from the other BOT. I'm thinking that the GET request is just ending too fast for the BOT to respond when the code is run outside the debugger and I have no idea on how to fix or extend the request. Any ideas?

Here's the relevant code:

```
public class EdwardComponent
{
    public static async Task<string> TalkToEdward(string userInput, string conversationID, string streamURL)
    {
        var DirectLineURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DirectLineURL"];
        var BearerToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BearerToken"];
        var DirectLineURLConversationID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DirectLineURLConversationID"];
        DirectLineURLConversationID = DirectLineURLConversationID.Replace("abc123", conversationID);

        var postclient = new RestClient(DirectLineURLConversationID);
        var postrequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        postrequest.AddHeader("Authorization", BearerToken);
        postrequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        postrequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        var idv = new { id = "user1" };
        postrequest.AddBody(new { type = "message", from = idv, text = userInput });
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var postresponse = postclient.ExecuteAsPost(postrequest, "POST");

        var getrequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        getrequest.AddHeader("Authorization", BearerToken);
        var getresponse = await postclient.ExecuteGetTaskAsync(getrequest);

        string content = getresponse.Content.ToString();
        return content;
    }
}
```

}

Here is the correct serialized response from debugging:

[Activity 0 is the message sent, Activity 1 is the response from BOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REVdM.png)

Here is the response when ran outside debugger:

[Only Activity 0 returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REVdM.png)

Comment: You can try to set a delay before you retrieve activities,and check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using a small delay and a loop that will continue making the GET request until the Bot responds.